# What's the recommended way to expose standard colors in WPF

Tags: wpf

I would normally just create a static class like StandardFooColors and create a static field for each standard color.  However, with WPF I could also put these in a resource dictionary.  Just wondering if there is a recommended way to do this or if it is 6 of 1 or half dozen of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a ResourceDictionary.
This will also give you the option to associate color (xaml) files with different "skins", and easily switch between them on-the-fly.

Plus, it is easier to define complex colors and brushes in xaml than it is in code.